Plotting complimentary error function issues
My problem is that the y-axis for when running the matlab code below starts at $x/S_e  = 0$ when it should start at $x/S_e  = 0.6$. I've attached the correct plot and my wrong plot titled 'Function F(u).' Is there something with my code or the math? Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck here for hours now.
S_e = 500; %meters
alpha_b = deg2rad(10); %10 degrees to radians
H_b = 1.5; % meters
d_p = 3; %total profile depth 3 meters

% Calculating Q_0 [m^3/hour]
Q_0 = 330*H_b^(5/2)*sin(2*alpha_b);

% Kappa S [m^2/hour]
Kappa_s = Q_0/(d_p*alpha_b);

%Calculating t_full
t_full = 10862.4;

%Calculating t_bypassing_solution in t/t_b
t_b = (S_e^2*d_p)/(pi*Q_0*alpha_b)
t_bypassing_solution = t_b*[0.5, 1, 2];


% Define the range of y
y = linspace(-10000, 0, 10000);

for i = 1:length(t_bypassing_solution);
    u = y/sqrt(4*Kappa_s*t_bypassing_solution(i));

    % Compute erf(-u) and erfc(-u)
    erf_neg_u = erf(-u); 
    erfc_neg_u = 1-erf_neg_u;

    x1 = S_e*erfc_neg_u;

    plot(y, x1, 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    hold on;
end

xlabel('y (km)');
ylabel('x / S_e');




Can you explain what you want to plot? I.e. explain the problem you want to solve and show the equations.
